# Rails 5: When I set cookie store in development I get invalid authenticity token from devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise, session-storage

I have a Rails 5 app and am trying to share sessions with another subdomain.  I've adjusted `session_store.rb` to reflect the following:

```
if Rails.env.development?
    Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: "_your_app_session", domain: ".lvh.me"
else
```

But now when I sign in using `devise`, I get the following error:

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in Devise::SessionsController#create
```

If I add `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` to `ApplicationController`, it seems as though nothing happens and I fail my authorization with a `401 unauthorized` and it looks as though I've never signed in.

Comment: can you share your `application_controller.rb` ?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/4033/files).

Comment: Same thing happened when I added `same_site: :none` to my existing `cookie_store` setting. Adding `prepend: true` to `protect_from_forgery` does not work.